# Como evitar ciclo infinito na função/chamada que reduz o tamanho da letra?

Tags: jquery, css-font-size, ciclo-infinito

Criei esta pequena extensão de jQuery que visa reduzir o tamanho do texto através da definição `font-size` de CSS com base no `overflow` do seu contentor.

O funcionamento é simples, descobrir o tamanho de letra actual e retirar um pixel à mesma, aplicando depois uma nova definição de CSS para o elemento em questão:

```js
;(function ($) {

    $.fn.fitWidth = function( options ) {

        var opts = $.extend({
            min: "11"
        }, options );

        var tamanho = parseInt(this.css('font-size'));

        if (tamanho > opts.min) {
            return this.css({
                'font-size': tamanho-1        
            });
        }
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

**Contudo, existe um problema:**

Se a letra indicada pelo utilizador, ou até o valor mínimo por defeito não for suficientemente baixo para evitar o `overflow`, a chamada desta extensão vai causar um ciclo infinito:

```js
$('#wrap span').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        overflow = $this[0].scrollWidth > $this.width() ? true : false;

    if (overflow) {
        while (overflow) {
            $this.fitWidth({"min":'1'});
            overflow = $this[0].scrollWidth > $this.width() ? true : false;
        }
    }
});
```

<sup>Com mínimo de letra a **11** por exemplo, vamos ter um ciclo infinito.</sup>

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/CKmcg/) para mínimo de **1**, mas cuidado ao alterar o valor para testar, um ciclo infinito de JavaScript pode levar o navegador a para de funcionar.

[image: Exemplo a funcionar com letra mínima de 1]

## Pergunta:

Como posso alterar a extensão ou a chamada da mesma, de forma a evitar ciclos infinitos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira ideia que me vem é limitar o while ao tamanho atual em pixels, conforme o trecho abaixo:

```js
$('#wrap span').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        overflow = $this[0].scrollWidth > $this.width() ? true : false;

    if (overflow) {
        var size = parseInt($this.css('font-size'));
        while (overflow && size-- > 1) {
            $this.fitWidth({"min":'1'});
            overflow = $this[0].scrollWidth > $this.width() ? true : false;
        }
    }
});
```

Atualizei o exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKmcg/1/).

Obviamente seria bom fazer um tratamento quanto ao valor. E no caso de não conseguir recuperar um inteiro ou estar em outra unidade, poderia-se limitar a um número máximo que, embora menos elegante, evitaria travar o navegador ou a aba.

---

Alternativamente, a função adicionada ao jQuery poderia encapsular a lógica completa, simplificando o uso:

```js
;(function ($) {

    $.fn.fitWidth = function( options ) {

        var opts = $.extend({
            min: "11"
        }, options );

        this.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);
            var tamanho = parseInt($this.css('font-size'));

            var overflow = $this[0].scrollWidth > $this.width() ? true : false;
            while (overflow && tamanho > opts.min && tamanho-- > 1) {
                $this.css({
                    'font-size': tamanho
                });
                overflow = $this[0].scrollWidth > $this.width() ? true : false;
            }

        });
        return this;

    };
}( jQuery ));
```

O uso fica mais simples e a função encapsulada:

```js
$('#wrap span').fitWidth({"min":'1'});
```

Veja outra versão no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKmcg/2/).